# When should one website be split into two?

Tags: website-design

Someone wants me to make a website. He said it may be better to make two. They are both about cuisine, but it sounds like one is more towards ordering ingredients and one is more of a discussion platform. I'm going to meet with him tomorrow to get more requirements. My question is, when should a website be two websites? Is there any guidelines or philosophies, such as a single website should serve a single purpose?

Comment: Not necessarily. Remember when Netflix wanted to split their DVD ordering service from their online streaming and the fit people had because it was inconvenient? There aren't usually any guidelines, other than what your user base wants and what your client wants.

Comment: hmm if there aren't any guidelines I'm inclined not to do it as it would add more administrative overhead

Comment: It seems to me that this person is hoping to combine a forum of some sorts with an e-commerce platform, which is used pretty much everywhere. I think your first step is understanding scope and what they plan on doing.

Comment: (which is exactly what you're doing!)

Comment: I seriously think it's unfair this was closed as too broad when you could have asked for more details to the specific situation.

Comment: This happens a lot. In order to re-open it, you'll have to edit your question to be a little more specific. It's hard, I know, I've had similar situations in the passed, but you'll get used to it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend dividing the website into two tabs and giving them link like *examplewebsite.com/order* and *examplewebsite.com/discuss*. Making two separate websites for one business makes it seem divided while one company should make a whole. Even the link is easier to remember when there is only one.

I strongly disagree with the person who told you that you should have two separate websites even though it is the same business.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

This depends on the way the users will be accessing and using the site. If there is an enough amount of users that accesses directly PartB **and** from there don't go to PartA, then it might be an option to split the website so each part has its "own identity". (or access PartA just to access PartB).

As you don't have any usage information and if it is not possible to make an accurate guess I believe it is safer to build one site and consider the split in some future when there is enough information of its usage.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the scope of your website. But it sounds as if your "discussion platform" could enhance your "ordering platform" with a social experience aspect. For example, people can share experiences and tips in the discussion area, which could lead to more orders. Maybe you miss this opportunity if you split the sites.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking this is a vital question. Brings to mind the "malls" that were tried on the Internet and failed. ...which is because brick and mortar malls make sense because of geographical limitations. I have to get in my car and travel to the store. The web has no such limitation, hence "malls" don't make sense on the Internet. I can instantly click between sites located across the globe. So the convenience of proximity is no longer a benefit.

So the determination of splitting (or combining) a website is determined by how well the functions considered splitting serve your user base's expectations and frame of mind. Don't bore your user. If only half the functions on your site apply to what I seek, I'm bored with half your site and I'm likely to switch to a focused site where 80+ percent of functions apply to my interest.

I think better to error on the side of splitting, than boring.